# Geometric Prob. in a Pentagon

Tags: probability

Point $P$ is selected at random from the interior of the pentagon with vertices $A=(0,2)$, $B= (4,0)$, $C = (2\pi +1, 0)$, $D=(2\pi
+1,4)$, and $E=(0,4)$. What is the probability that $\angle APB$ is obtuse? Express your answer as a common fraction.

I have no clue on how to attack this problem. The only thing I can think of is the fact that AB^2 + AC^2 < BC^2 in an obtuse triangle, but I can't see how that applies here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint...
You need the area of the semicircle whose diameter is $AB$ divided by the area of the pentagon $ABCDE$

Comment: I have been staring at this problem for a few hours already, so I might be missing something simple. How do I know the whole semi fits in the pentagon? And besides intuition, how do I know all the points in the semi will make  obtuse angles and all the points outside will be acute ( I know the points on the semi will be right).

Comment: do you need any more help?

Comment: Yes. I edited it in my comment before :)

Comment: Ok, I figured out the whole semi will fit in the pentagon. But I still can't figure out the second part of my question.

Comment: The angle in a semicircle is a right angle, so if the chosen point is inside the semicircle, the angle will be obtuse. A simple diagram shows the highest point on the semicircle is below $ED$ because the radius is $\sqrt{5}<3$